# How to make remote connection to router and within that connect to local wifi device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Can someone explain me the possibility of such a connection?

Image to explain the scheme:

[image: Image to explain the scheme]

I have a remote router (4G). I have (2) local devices with IPs that I can access locally. (IP camera and solar panel system)

Questions are:

1. Is it possible to connect remotely to router and from there connect to local WiFi's to control devices.
2. What kind of connection I need to set up to connect to router first of all.
3. What kind of connection do I need to set up inside router to connect to local device without cable.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to connect remotely to router and from there connect to local WiFi's to control devices.

Yes, by using
[port-forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

This basically open ports on the router that are directed to your devices.
If your public IP is `1.2.3.4`, then you may set port 200 to direct
to the first device. You may choose to even direct to the RDP port,
so you may connect remotely via RDP. (Very good password is required.)

See also
[How To Set Up Port Forwarding - Portforward](https://portforward.com/).

[image]

> What kind of connection I need to set up to connect to router first of all.

You may use your public IP to connect. If the IP can change, you may use
[Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS)
that allows you to refer to the router by a name that never changes.
Your router may support DDNS, or you may set it up on the computer
using software such as
[Dynu](https://www.dynu.com/en-US).

> What kind of connection do I need to set up inside router to connect to local device without cable.

The local network is enough.

The setup becomes much more complicated if you insist upon VPN access
to the router. This either requires using an advanced router that can
act as a VPN server, or setting up your own VPN server on your computer.

(Note: All these concepts might be new for you and you might have many
questions to ask. Before doing that here, please study in depth the
above links and search the internet for the information.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll say very unlikely. The biggest problem is that I doubt that you are getting your *own* public IP with a router that has cellular/4G WAN. Most likely you'll be behind something like [CGNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

Besides the router may not have any support in hosting a VPN server. (That part can be solved by using another host in the "local" network as the VPN server though, as long as the router allows port forwarding to be configured on it.)

If you really want to access your devices remotely, you'll probably need to host a VPN server on some VPS host or so that is "exposed" to the Internet with a public IP that is solely for its use. Then you configure your devices (both the "local" ones and the "remote" ones) to join the VPN by connecting to the VPN server. (Or you can connect only those that provide "services" to the server and configure port forwarding on the VPS host instead, if you want those services to be accessible from the Internet directly.)

Note that connecting devices to a VPN does NOT necessarily mean that they will be made to access the Internet via it.